# Link Changes Color On Multiple Hovers

Tags: javascript, html, hover

I was wondering how it may be possible to change the text color of my anchor multiple times, different colors each time said anchor is hovered over. I have scoured the internet and StackOverflow, and this has to be the closest thing I came to:

http://www.codecademy.com/es/donvomar/codebits/xIEpDx

That link bears the same general idea of hovering over something multiple times and it changing color each time.

I did take a look at the code, but thought of two things to fix: one, I am not familiar with jQuery, but minimally with JS; and two, that I want to specify my colors; I noticed his were random. To give you a picture, here's my code just for the (empty) link and its styling:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
         <a href = ""><div class = "menu">Text block for demonstration</div></a>
     <style>
        .menu {
        font-family: Bebas Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        color: white;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 300px;
        clear: both;
        background-color: black;
        }
    </style>

    </body>
</html>
```

**To sum it all up:** Basically, I want the text to change color each time it is hovered over, be able to specify the colors, and loop them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="test">hello world!</a>
```

**JS**

```
var arr = ['#f00', '#0f0', '#00f']; // Just add more if you like
var i = 0;
var start_over = arr.length;

$("#test").mouseenter(function(){

    i++;
    if (i == start_over) { 
        i = 0; 
    }

    $(this).css('color', arr[i]);

});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/53GSD/1/)**

Comment: Congrats on hitting 2K

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/V7qGx/

```
onmouseover = function() {
    this.style.color = colors[this.dataset.n++ % colors.length];
}
onmouseout = function() {
    this.style.color = '';
}
```